# Discord's OAuth2 Implementation on Flutter

Tags: flutter, oauth-2.0, discord

I'd like to know on where to get started with Discord's OAuth2 for Flutter. I've tried with the examples of OAuth2 Package and OhAuth2. I've set a website with Flask for the login and it works perfectly, I don't know how to make the connection between the Website's authentication and sending that info to flutter.

Oauth2 and OhAuth2 Examples and the Flask Setup for discord's OAuth2.

Comment: In flutter side, do you mean you have test connection with this package https://github.com/dart-lang/oauth2 and it did not work? or could you provide error message.

Comment: I've tried to do the connection with OhAuth2 https://github.com/murtaza0xFF/OhAuth2/tree/master/example and it did send me to the login page but once i authotize it doesnt come back to my main screen. I've no clue on how to do the login and retrieve the user's info and discord channels. I cant't find any examples online specific for Flutter.